# Mandar dados de windows forms para uma api

Tags: c#, api, winforms

Como faço para enviar um cadastro em c# windows forms para uma api?
Só consegui encontrar de exibir o que já está na api.

Comment: pesquise pelo `WebClient`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient?view=net-7.0

Answer (score -2):

O endpoint da API que você está tentando enviar o dados possui o método POST?
Sugiro dar uma olhada na documentação da API para verificar o que é possível fazer ou não.
Se a API permitir o método POST, verifique se você não está tentando enviar os dados por meio de um GET, ou se o endpoint que você está utilizando é o correto, além de verificar se é necessário algum método de autenticação e se os headers e body da solicitação estão corretos.